# Using an audio cable (or similar) to create unidirectional communication from a secure server

Tags: windows, networking, security, certificate-authority, pki

I'm interested in exploring how a semi-offline Root CA can be used to update CRLs to the sub CA's.  [This answer on Security.SE mentions using an audio cable for this purpose.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/aia-crl-locations-for-offline-root/24083#comment39085_24083)

Doe anyone have details on how an Audio cable (or similar) can be used to create a unidirectional path of communication?

Since I'm a .Net programmer, I'm also open to code samples, drivers, etc that may enable this scenario.

Comment: Maybe you could have one server generate QR codes and display them on a monitor, then the other server(s) could read the codes with cameras pointed at the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Using audio to communicate between 2 servers sounds way more complicated than necessary, not to mention error-prone and fragile. You'd end up implementing some kind of modem in software. The complexity of that "modem" could be anything from morse code on up, but I don't think it's going to be terribly efficient no matter what.

There are so many other methods of unidirectional communication you could choose from instead:

- You could use a unidirectional serial connection: only TX and ground are wired, leaving RX unconnected.
- You could use a half-duplex ethernet connection. Same idea, only this time you have to wire the RX pair to a dummy dead-end ethernet hub in order to spoof link integrity.
- You could have an additional secure device on a network between the two systems that forwards traffic in only one direction (basically a firewall).